# Coding Survival Time: How to handle if a subject dies before your outcome (heart failure, HF) AND they have a HF event =1?

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model

I am running a cox-regression model and am struggling with how to define my survival time to event (heart failure) if their time to HF (=1) AFTER they have died? i.e. it is documented they have a case of HF, but this is AFTER the date of death/ this person dies before developing the event.

Variables:
. HF: binary (1 = event; 0 = no event)
. Time to HF
. Time to death
. Death date
. Death: binary (1= event; 0 = no event)

1. Do I keep HF=1 and replace HF survival time with death survival time
2. Do I replace HF=1 to HF=0 and replace HF survival time with death survival time

I hope this makes sense. Thank you for your time and support.

Comment: Might this have been a situation where the individual died and a later autopsy found that death was from heart failure? As an answer says, "first dying and later coming back to life only to experience heart failure is not what really happened." Please address that by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You should recode to represent whatever truly occurred for this patient, *but only* if you can work out what that is. Presumably, first dying and later coming back to life only to experience heart failure is not what really happened.

If you cannot be confident whether and when this person experienced heart failure and/or died, I would treat it as missing data.

Comment: Your first paragraph sums this up nicely (+1). I don't know about treating this as "missing data" if an important part of the model is time to death, for example in a multi-state or competing risks model. The date of death seems to be well documented, the open questions are probably whether death resulted from heart failure and how the model handles heart failure that only shows up at death.